# How to create TextView programmatically?

Tags: android

I have created some TextView in the view ml, about 5 of them. But the problem is that after I read from xml file the values come, more than 5 sometimes, and there is no limit. It could be better more than 10. However if I can create the TextView from the activity, then I think I can do it somehow.

Comment: please rephrase your question, it's quite difficult to understand it in it's current form...

Comment: what i am facing is that i have an xml with multible data and i want to save that data and show it to the user what i used to do is that i create one TextView for every field i have but some time the xml file bring more data that i want to show it but its not linked ti a TextView mybe i need an array to save all my data and show it in one TextView is that currect?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want it add to a view called `containingView`,

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(containingView.getContext());
myTextView.setText("alshareef");
containingView.addView(myTextView);
```